# Migrate theme from Magento Community to Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2-enterprise, magento2-cloud

I am creating a website in Magento2. I am currently working in the Theme Creation. My client suddenly have plans to go to Magento Enterprise/Cloud. Can someone help if my theme will work there or do I have to write the theme from scratch?